# T-SQL Copy Row to Same Table and Another Table with Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, copy

I'm using Transact-SQL, for example let's say I have...

**TABLE_1**

```
ID_MAIN  DATA
1        red
2        blue
```

**TABLE_2**

```
ID_SUB  ID_MAIN  TYPE
3       1        soft
4       2        rough
```

...and for each entry in "TABLE_1" i want to copy it to "TABLE_1" with a new unique id (primary key) and for each one of those entries in "TABLE_1" i also want to copy the entries that reference it (foreign key) in "TABLE_2" with a new id as well.

**TABLE_1**

```
ID_MAIN  DATA
1        red
2        blue
3        red
4        blue
```

**TABLE_2**

```
ID_SUB  ID_MAIN  TYPE
3       1        soft
4       2        rough
5       3        soft
6       4        rough
```

I understand how you can copy a entry and change certain fields as such

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (ID_MAIN, DATA)
    SELECT NEWID(), DATA
    FROM TABLE_1
```

My question is more geared to how I can iterate threw each entry in `TABLE_1`, copy the entries with new ids, and per entry basis add new rows to `TABLE_2` which reference those ids from `TABLE_1`

Hopefully this makes sense, not sure if it does to me haha

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are TABLE_1.ID_MAIN and TABLE_2.ID_SUB identify fields (meaning you don't have to intentionally insert the next value), or not (meaning you have to do some math to intentionally insert the next value) ?

Comment: @JimHorn TABLE_1.ID_MAIN and TABLE_2.ID_SUB are of uniqueidentifier  type created with newid(). so they are simply identification fields.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want something like:

```
INSERT INTO
    Table_2
    (
      table_2_id
      , table_1_id
      , type
    )
SELECT
    table_2_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.table_1_id)
    , table_1_id = a.table_1_id
    , type
      CASE
        WHEN a.data = 'red' THEN 'soft'
        WHEN a.data = 'blue' THEN 'rough'
      END
FROM
    table_1 a
```

This would take all records from Table 1, insert them into Table 2, assign the type based on the table 1 data column, and increment the ID for Table 2.

Comment: sorry but that is not what i am looking to accomplish. the data and type  fields are simply place holders for the example. i am more concerned with copying each row in both tables but maintaining the relationship between the two entries in each table. so if row 1 in table 2 is a foreign key to row 1 in table 1 i want maintain that relationship for the respective copies, only difference is that the row 1 copy will have a different uniqueidentifier

Comment: so if we did a copy then row 2 in table 2 would contain a foreign key for row 2 in table 1 but the row 2 in table 1 would have a different uniqueidentifier then its parent which it copied